# Only shows one tetview rating

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app to help people know when it is time for a phone upgrade. I ran into a little problem along the way, mainly when trying to test the functionality of the code. I rated all 6 categories and pressed the continue button. Only the rating for the "Game" shows up. I don't know what is going on since I have all six textviews included.

[Shows only one rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn4to.png)

Java:

```
package com.inducesmile.phoneupgrade;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView; 

public class Page1 extends Activity {
    TextView tvBatt, tvPerf, tvAttr, tvCam, tvVal, tvGame;
    RatingBar rateBattery, ratePerformance, rateCamera, rateValue, rateGaming, rateAttractiveness;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page1);
        Init();
    }

    public void Init() {
        tvBatt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBatt);
        tvPerf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPerf);
        tvAttr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAttr);
        tvCam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCam);
        tvVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvVal);
        tvGame = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGame);
        rateBattery = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rateBatt);
        rateCamera = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rateCam);
        rateGaming = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rateGame);
        rateValue = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rateValue);
        ratePerformance = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.Performance);
        rateAttractiveness = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rateAttr);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnCont) {
            String strBatt = String.valueOf(rateBattery.getRating());
            tvBatt.setText(strBatt);
            String strAttr = String.valueOf(rateAttractiveness.getRating());
            tvAttr.setText(strAttr);
            String strCam = String.valueOf(rateCamera.getRating());
            tvCam.setText(strCam);
            String strPerf = String.valueOf(ratePerformance.getRating());
            tvPerf.setText(strPerf);
            String strGame = String.valueOf(rateGaming.getRating());
            tvGame.setText(strGame);
            String strVal = String.valueOf(rateValue.getRating());
            tvVal.setText(strVal);
        }
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
android:background="#FFF000">

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="How Important Are These Features to You?"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Continue"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/btnCont"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Performance"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rateBatt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rateGame"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rateBatt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rateCam"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rateGame"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rateGame"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rateGame" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rateAttr"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rateCam" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rateValue"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rateAttr"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Performance"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rateValue"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Battery Life:"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Gaming:"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rateGame"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Camera:"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rateGame"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Attractiveness:"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rateAttr"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Value:"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rateValue"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Performance:"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rateValue"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvBatt"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="____" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvGame"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="____" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvCam"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="____" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvAttr"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="____" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvVal"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
    android:text="____" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvPerf"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
    android:text="____" />
```

Comment: your code looks fine to me, I even compiled that code to test it http://imgur.com/c6RPZ76, have you try to rebuild/clean your project? If you're using Android Studio, go to Build->Clean Project and then Build->Rebuild Project

Comment: I have gone over this a few times myself.  I can't find anything amiss.  Perhaps check your logCat to see if something is happening.  A minor error that is not crashing the program...

Comment: @Wilik Yes, that was it. I don't understand why Android Studio does not check for code updates sometimes when you are running it on a phone. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yeah, I experienced that too sometimes. I will post that as answer, please mark it as accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, try rebuild/clean the project.

If you're using Android Studio, go to Build -> Clean Project and then Build -> Rebuild Project.